# pagination in web application

Tags: javascript, pagination

Is there any prefect suggestion for data pagination?

I do not want use pure client side(for example,the [jquery pagination plugin](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm)):

Pull all the data,and paging them in the client(this is simple,but cost time to load).

Any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that depends on your server-side. If you're developing with Rails there is a nice gem for pagination: will_paginate ( https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/installation ) with some Railscasts available: http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=will_paginate

Comment: We use .net in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes server side pagination. For example with sql you could have a query like that

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE 1 ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 5,10
```

Where 10 is the number of records you want for each page to display and 5 is the record you want to start from.

If your current page is page 2 and the sum of all your records is 100 and you want to display 10 result for every page then you will end up with 100/10 = 10 pages with 10 results each. You can get the current page using url parameters.

Comment: I know how it work. I just wonder how to keep the variable in the client side,for example, click 1 will load data from 1-10 ,click 2 will load data from 11-20. Is there an pugin can be used out-of-box?

Comment: i have no experience with .net so i cant answer that one.